# Clang fails to compile with -m32 on open SUSE Leap 15

Tags: c++, clang, opensuse

I've a SUSE Leap 15 virtual machine, and installed clang5 by zypper and I want to compile a software, that must be compiled to 32bit, but it seems clang wont compile a simple example with -m32. (necessary 32bit libs are installed).

I'm trying to compile this file:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
int main()                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

  auto x = 2;                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  std::cout << x << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                     

}
```

With the following command (without -m32 it works fine):

clang++ main.cpp -o alma -std=c++17 -m32 -v

```
clang version 5.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_501/final 312548)
Target: i386-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Candidate multilib: 32;@m32
Selected multilib: 32;@m32
 "/usr/bin/clang-5.0.1" -cc1 -triple i386-unknown-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -fuse-init-array -target-cpu i586 -v -dwarf-column-info -debugger-tuning=gdb -resource-dir /usr/lib64/clang/5.0.1 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7/x86_64-suse-linux/32 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/lib64/clang/5.0.1/include -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -std=c++17 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/martonka/test -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 227 -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o /tmp/main-d5b20e.o -x c++ main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 5.0.1 based upon LLVM 5.0.1 default target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7
 /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7/x86_64-suse-linux/32
 /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../include/c++/7/backward
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib64/clang/5.0.1/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --hash-style=both --build-id --enable-new-dtags --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o alma /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../crti.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/32/crtbegin.o -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/32 -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7 -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux/lib -L/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../.. -L/usr/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/main-d5b20e.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/32/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../crtn.o
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../libm.so when searching for -lm
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../libc.so when searching for -lc
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../crt1.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../crti.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `/usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../crtn.o' is incompatible with i386 output
clang-5.0.1: error: unable to execute command: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
clang-5.0.1: error: linker command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
```

" g++ main.cpp -o alma -std=c++17 -m32 " works fine.

It seems the problem is that clang passes the 64 bit versions of crtn.o, crti.o and crt1.o to ld.
If I just compile an object file:
clang++ main.cpp -std=c++17 -c -o alma.o
and then execute the above linker command with crtn.o, crti.o and crt1.o paths fixed, then it works.

It looks like clang thinks that g++ is under /usr/lib/ (which is true on ubuntu, centos, but not on suse),  and it just adds ../../../ to reach the 32bit libraries, which is clearly wrong.

How can this be fixed?

UPDATE: After a bit more searching

here is an open suse bug for this: bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1051881#c4

And an open llvm bug: bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12108

In the second one, there is a workaround:

```
cd /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/32
ln -s /usr/lib/crt1.o
ln -s /usr/lib/crti.o
ln -s /usr/lib/crtn.o
```

But clang still gives warnings:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../libm.so when searching for -lm
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/7/../../../libc.so when searching for -lc
```

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Install gnulibc  and c++ standard library for 32 bit development. Your linker making attempt to link with 64bit libraries, and failing.

Comment: As I mentioned above:
g++ can compile with -m32, and If I create only an object file with clang, and fix the path in the linker command printed on the output (line 23), then it links and runs.
So everything is installed.

Comment: Including libclang-common-3.8-dev i686 ?

Comment: I cant find it with zypper search.
These are installed (rpm -qa | grep clang) :
    clang5-checker-5.0.1-lp150.6.1.x86_64
    clang5-devel-32bit-5.0.1-lp150.6.1.x86_64
    clang5-devel-5.0.1-lp150.6.1.x86_64
    clang5-5.0.1-lp150.6.1.x86_64
    libclang5-32bit-5.0.1-lp150.6.1.x86_64
    libclang5-5.0.1-lp150.6.1.x86_64

Comment: Simply check for the clang-devel `i686` not `x86_64`

Comment: clang5-devel-32bit-5.0.1-lp150.6.1.x86_64 is installed.

and there is an open suse bug for this:
https://bugzilla.suse.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1051881#c4

And an open llvm bug:
https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12108